Number of elements in polynomial quotient ring when the ring is not a field

How many elements are in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]/<p(x)>$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$?

I know that when $\mathbb{F}$ is a field containing $m$ elements, then the number of elements in $\mathbb{F}[x]/<p(x)>$ is $m^n$ and also went over the proof, which makes complete sense to me.
My question is:

Does the existence of zero divisors (2) in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ change something in the answer or is it still $4^n$?

Remark:
the general idea is that we can choose representatives for each coset of the form $f(x)+<p(x)>$ where $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$, and then deduce the number of possible elements is $4^n$ from a counting argument for the possibilities of coefficients.
I belive everything remains the same in the case I mentioned above, and that also cosets are distinct, meaning the number of different cosets is not less than $4^n$ and not affected by zero-divisors. Just wanted to make sure I am not missing something that makes this argument ill-defined (just making sure this is not another reason for only working in $\mathbb{F}[x]/<p(x)>$ for fields $\mathbb{F}$ and not just rings).

@Randall Sorry about that. Edited

@Randall : can you please elaborate? why do they fail when $p$ isn't irreducible? And if they fail, then what is the number of elements? Thank you!

Unfortunately, your claim is not true. It is not so much zero divisors, but rather simply the existence of non-zero non-units (in this case, they are one and the same). One easy counter-example is the polynomial $p(x)=2$. You should convince yourself that then $\Bbb{Z}_4[x]/p(x) \cong \Bbb{Z}_2[x]$, which is of course infinite.
The argument holds if the leading coefficient of $p$ is a unit, however.

Edit: I'll try to address your concerns.
To be clear, you were hoping that $\Bbb{Z}_4[x]/(p(x))$ was finite, preferably that every coset was (uniquely) representable by a polynomial of degree $<\text{deg}(p)$. Hopefully it is clear that if  $\Bbb{Z}_4[x]/(2) \cong \Bbb{Z}_2[x]$, then we have a counter-example.
Let us prove this. Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb{Z}_4[x]\to \Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ given by reducing the coefficients of the polynomials mod $2$, i.e.
$$a_nx^n +\dots + a_0 \mapsto [a_n]_2 x^n+\dots+[a_0]_2,$$
where $[a]_2$ signifies $a$ mod $2$. It should be clear that this map is surjective, and that a polynomial maps to $0$, i.e. lies in the kernel, if and only if every coefficient is even, i.e. if it lies in the ideal generated by $2$. Thus, the kernel is $(2)$, and by the first isomorphism theorem,
$$\Bbb{Z}_4[x]/(2) \cong \Bbb{Z}_2[x].$$
Note that this argument does not fail for $\Bbb{Z}[x]$! Indeed, quotients of this ring by polynomials may be infinite as well, e.g. we have $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2) \cong \Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ too! (by the exact same argument).
This is again exactly because $\Bbb{Z}$ is not a field either, and this also shows that it is not the zero divisors that is the problem. Rather, anytime you have an element of the base ring that is neither zero nor a unit, a "non-zero non-unit", such as $2$, you cannot use the standard argument for fields to show that the quotient can be expressed as polynomials of lower degree.
For example, consider $x^2-3$ and $p(x) = 2x$. There is no $q(x)$ you can multiply $p(x)$ with such that $p(x)q(x) = x^2+\text{lower order terms}$, because that would correspond the the existence of an element $b$ such that $2b = 1$. Thus, the usual polynomial division argument fails. Again, nothing to do with zero divisors, and everything to do with elements that are not invertible.

Dear @SomeCallMeTim:
Unfortunately, I can't understand the argument here and why it fails when we consider $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for example.
Will you please elaborate on how to prove the isomorphism you mentioned and explain what makes this impossible when we don't have "non-zero non-units" (not sure what does it mean exactly). Thank you!

@Dr.John I have edited my answer, hope that clears it up.

THank you so much for this detailed answer, which really helped!

I upvoted for your handling of $\Bbb{Z}_4$ is correct. I do want to add that non-invertibility in itself is not always a problem. For a well known example prove that the quotient ring
$$\Bbb{Z}_6[x]/\langle 2x-3\rangle$$
is finite. Of course, an argument similar to this shows that $\Bbb{Z}_6[x]/\langle 2x\rangle$ is infinite.

@JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the nice example, non-invertibility is of course not sufficient to show that the quotient is infinite, but it is the reason that the general argument breaks down.
